# Moving resources from one VM to another VM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtual-machine

Consider two (4 core and 8 GB) virtual machines(vm_1 and vm_2) are created out of one physical physical machine (8 core 16 GB). Can I transfer one core(cores or memory) from vm_1(3 core) to vm_2(4 core)  after initial creation of VM  ?

**Edit :-**

Sébastien Stormacq  answered in context of AWS but I am using  on premises hardware with a virtualisation technology. So please answer in context of that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your information about how virtual machines are allocated on physical hardware is incorrect.  Do not assume anything about physical hardware, as this is not documented by Amazon.

With Amazon EC2, you can stop your instance at anytime, assign another instance type, and restart your instance.  The instance type is how you can control the amount of vCPU and memory allocated to your instance.

A couple of compatibility rules apply, be sure to read the doc at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html

Comment: When you say `With Amazon EC2, you can stop your instance at anytime, assign another instance type, and restart your instance` I believe you mean vertical scaling here. Right ? Ok if I talk VM (not in context of AWS) whic is created from physical machine , can we move the resources across VM after creation ?

Comment: Sorry, your question was tagged as 'amazon-web-services' so I answered with Amazon EC2.  If you are using on premises hardware with a virtualisation technology, please clarify this in the question, and I am sure someone will help you

Comment: Sure but your answer is helpful please don't delete it :0